# If $A$ is $n \times n$ skew-symmetric matrix where $n$ is an odd integer number, then $A$ is singular.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, skew-symmetric-matrices

In order to answer, I must first state whether the statement is true or false, followed by an explanation

> If $A$ is $n \times n$ skew-symmetric matrix where $n$ is an odd integer number, then $A$ is singular.

The answer is True:
\begin{align}
A^{\mathsf{T}} &= -A \\
|A^{\mathsf{T}}| &= |-A| \\[1pt]
|A| &= (-1)^n |A| 
\end{align}

That is the step I know, but I need assistance with what follows how to prove that it is True.

---

Tanks to @Sammy Black
I have got the right answer to the question - the answer is:

$ᵀ = -$

$|ᵀ| = |-|$

$|| = (-1)^ ||$

$|| = -||$

$2|A| = 0 $

$2|A|/2 = 0 $

$|A| = 0$

therefore the answer is true A is singular since $|A| = 0$

Comment: You need to show that $n$ odd implies $|A|=0$. Take your work so far, and add to it the assumption that $n$ is odd. See if you can conclude $|A|=0$. Alternatively, you can show that $|A|\ne 0$ implies $n$ even.

Comment: |A|=(−1)^n|A|

we will have |A|=(−1)|A| but what is after that

Comment: Don’t switch from $|A|$ to $A$.

Comment: you mean like that right 2|A|=0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have correctly deduced that the scalar $d = |A|$ satisfies the equation
$$
d = (-1)^n d 
$$
for any natural $n$. Using the fact that $n$ is odd, $(-1)^n = -1$, so
$d = -d$
or
$$
2d = 0.
$$

Here's where we need to assume that the characteristic of the ring of scalars that the matrices are defined over *is not $2$.* For instance, if the matrices are over the field $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, where characteristic is $0$, we're good. We may conclude that $d = 0$, hence the matrix is singular.

---

However, over a field of characteristic $2$, where $-1 = 1$ and $2 = 0$, we cannot reach this conclusion, since $2d = 0$ is true for any $d$. In fact, in such a situation, being skew-symmetric and being symmetric *are the same thing!* As an explicit, example, consider the $3 \times 3$ identity matrix, which is skew-symmetric over, say, $\mathbb{F}_2$, and is certainly not singular.

Comment: so all I need is to write at the end 2d=0. so A is singular or should I divide the 2d/2 = 0  so we have d = 0 ??

Comment: **Assuming that the characteristic is not $2$** (maybe this is an implicit assumption), you can divide by $2$ and you're done.

Comment: thanks, Sammy 
i found the answer

 Aᵀ=−A
 

|Aᵀ|=|−A|


|A|=(−1)n|A|


|A|=−|A|


2A=0


therefore the answer is true A is singular since 2A=0